# Detect and compare Tumblr {block:Permalink}

Tags: tumblr, permalinks, prerender

OK, so I'm trying to find out if there is any way to detect and compare the URL/permalink of Tumblr's posts/pages with a custom URL.

The main idea is to use Tumblr as a store/selling platform powered by PayPal, and have the PayPal links prerendered within the head of the page - to speed up the payment process - by using the prerender link (below). *However, there should be only one link (as below) per Tumblr post, and not for all posts.*

```
<link rel="prerender" href="http://www.paypal.com/pay-link-for-my-product-1">
```

So what I have so far is this:

```
{block:Permalink} //detects if Tumblr URL is a post/page
{Permalink} //gets the URL of the post/page
{/block:Permalink}
```

What I need is something like this:

```
{block:Permalink} //detects if Tumblr URL is a post/page
{Permalink=http://example.com/post/my-product-1} //not working
{/block:Permalink}
```

I have no idea is this is possible using the Tumblr code and I do not need a javascript alternative as it will be useless for this purpose.

Comment: Sadly this is not possible as you can't assign or reassign Tumblr variables.